# JQuery DataTable select all the checkboes in a single row on button click

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have tried but no success.

When I click Save button on the right side (See the screen shot below). I want to select all the checkbox status(true/false) in that row only and dump them in an array.
If I do this on button click `organizationsTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data().viewAccess;`
I get old value not current status of checkbox.

**DATATABLE**

```
var organizationsTable = $("#organizations").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "filter": true,
        "paging": false,
        "info": true,
        "searching": true,
        "orderMulti": false,
        "aaData": myjson,
        "columnDefs":
        [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": true,
                "searchable": false,
            },
            {
                "targets": [1],
                "visible": true,
                "searchable": false,
            },
            {
                'targets': 2,
                "orderable": false,
                'className': 'centert-align',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return data;
                }
            },
            {
                'targets': 3,
                "orderable": false,
                'className': 'centert-align',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    if (type === 'display') {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" ' + ((data == 1) ? 'checked' : '') + ' id="input' + row.id + '" class="filter-ck" />';
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            {
                'targets': 4,
                "orderable": false,
                'className': 'centert-align',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    if (type === 'display') {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" ' + ((data == 1) ? 'checked' : '') + ' id="input' + row.id + '" class="filter-ck" />';
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            {
                'targets': 5,
                "orderable": false,
                'className': 'centert-align',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    if (type === 'display') {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" ' + ((data == 1) ? 'checked' : '') + ' id="input' + row.id + '" class="filter-ck" />';
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            {
                'targets': 6,
                "orderable": false,
                'className': 'centert-align',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    if (type === 'display') {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" ' + ((data == 1) ? 'checked' : '') + ' id="input' + row.id + '" class="filter-ck" />';
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            {
                'targets': 7,
                "orderable": false,
                'className': 'centert-align',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    if (type === 'display') {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" ' + ((data == 1) ? 'checked' : '') + ' id="input' + row.id + '" class="filter-ck" />';
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            {
                'targets': 8,
                "orderable": false,
                'className': 'centert-align',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    if (type === 'display') {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" ' + ((data == 1) ? 'checked' : '') + ' id="input' + row.id + '" class="filter-ck" />';
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            }
        ],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "roleId" },
            { "data": "orgId" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "viewAccess" },
            { "data": "createAccess" },
            { "data": "editAccess" },
            { "data": "deleteAccess" },
            { "data": "authAccess" },
            { "data": "publishAccess" },
            {
                "orderable": false,
                data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<button type="submit" class="btn green linkorg_save cancel">SAVE</button>'
                }
            }
        ],
        'order': [1, 'asc']
    });
```

**BUTTON Click**

```
$('#organizations').on('click', 'button.linkorg_save', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        });
```

**HERE IS THE SCREEN SHOT**
[Grid ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTXj3.jpg)

**UPDATE: Style out after on Change event**
[ERROR after on change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17o7u.jpg)

Comment: See [Multiple columns](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/basic/multiple-columns/) example for [jQuery DataTables Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the status of the checkbox, assign different classes (for example, `access-view`) to each checkbox and check the state of the checkbox in real time as shown below.

```js
$('#organizations').on('click', '.btn', function(){
    // ... skipped ...

    var hasAccessView = $('.access-view', $(this).parents('tr')).is(':checked');
});
```

For alternative method of handling of checkboxes in a table powered by jQuery DataTables, use [jQuery DataTables Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) plug-in. See [Multiple columns](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/basic/multiple-columns/) example demonstrating use of multiple columns with checkboxes.

Comment: @gyrocode-com Thanks for the reply. Do you have any working code example to show with JQuery DataTables Checkboxes for my situation?. I am trying with it but don't know how to select checkboxes in a row on a button click with Checkboxes plugin. Any help. Then i accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can update cell data when you click on checkbox. That way you will keep your table data consistent.

```
$('#organizations').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function (e) {
    var td = $(this).closest('td');
    var value = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
    organizationsTable.cell(td).data(value).draw();
});
```

Comment: This is working but when i click on checkboxes there style changes and become small. CSS or something out.

Comment: Try calling `draw` function. I have updated the answer.

Comment: still no success. I have update the answer and added new screen shot at the end of my question. Why this is happening?